# Background video full-width but not height (ideally without JS)

Tags: css, html, video

I’ve searched here and elsewhere for the answer to this, but can’t find it.

I know that this is similar to other questions that have been asked, but bear with me.

I want to have a video background for a site, where the background covers 100% of the width, but only a specific, pixel-defined height (say, 500px). Similar to what is on the current AirBnB front page: https://www.airbnb.com/.

And, I’d like to try to do this with just HTML/CSS, and without using JS/jQuery, if at all possible (though if necessary I’ll use it).

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with setting div's height and display:inline-block for the video?

Comment: Hi artm... I don’t seem to be able to get it to work this way. Any examples? Thanks.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**CENTERING TRICK**

We could try to center the video using negative top (or margin-top) or left (or margin-left) values, but getting the right number of pixels to offset the video by is not easy. I acutally tried using calc() and the viewport units, it worked in Firefox and failed in Chrome and Safari, and overall it looked really arcane. Not a good solution!

So how do we center stuff that is wider or taller than the viewport, if we don’t know its exact dimensions? Easy! We make a big-ass container that is both bigger than the video and bigger than the viewport.

Here’s the rough idea in a picture:

[image]

```
#myvid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #myvid {
    height: 300%; top: -100%;
    /* or height: 200%; top: -50%;
       or height: 400%; top: -150%; */
  }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  #myvid {
    width: 300%; left: -100%;
    /* or width: 200%; left: -50%;
       or width: 400%; left: -150%; */
  }
}
```

The dashed outline is still our viewport, the light rectangle our video, and the dark area represents our big-ass container. We can then use any CSS centering technique of our choice (say, Flexbox) to center the video inside the container.

But guess what works like a container that automatically centers a video? The  element! So we can skip creating a  and using CSS centering techniques! Now we just need to make our video element way too tall or way too wide and let the browser handle the centering automatically and by default (it acts a bit like a  with a background-size:contain background image).

**FULL REFERENCE** - http://fvsch.com/code/video-background/

Comment: Hi Tibbers,

Thanks, but unfortunatley this does not do what I need. Once the height in this CSS is set to a pixel value instead of a percentage, then the video no longer stretches 100% of the width of the screen. Any other way of tackling this?

Comment: Give you a plus for your question. I will play around it and take a look for the possible solutions.

Comment: Hi here it is! http://fvsch.com/code/video-background/ - Absolutely everything what you need! I've bookmarked it for myself couple of days ago. Enjoy and good luck!

Comment: Updated the answer, hope your satisfied. If so accept the answer please. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Tibbers, thanks again, but unfortunately this is still not what I’m trying to do. I had already seen the fvsch.com article before asking the question, but it also doesn’t explain how to have a video with 100% width, but _less_ than 100% height (like how the front page of AirBnB appears: https://www.airbnb.com). If you have any idea how I can do this, it would be great to know! And thanks for your help regardless!

Comment: No worries and good luck! Unfortunately next hope I will find the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried utilising viewport scaling?

```
<video id="video" width="100vw" height="500px" controls autoplay>
    <source src="content/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="content/video/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Here you can see that the width is being set to 100% of the viewport width which equates to `window.innerWidth` in javascript.

Also, setting a fixed height will severely limit your websites ability to be responsive.

---

**UPDATE**

To date, we are still unable to set a `background-vdeo` in CSS, however the following snippet should help people get by in the mean time.

As @ummahusla mentioned, there is an issue in relation to trying to override the aspect ratio of the video, becuase the video will always center in the middle of the video box. Most screens are 16:9 so maintaining that ratio in your videos *should* prevent this.

Note the use of the `poster` image on the video - this will stop your site from looking sparce prior to the video being loaded.

Using pure CSS and HTML:

```css
video#bgvid {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  z-index: -100;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
}
h3 {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="bgvid" poster="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <source src="https://11-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/2754/1/38772314/89366703.mp4?expires=1480575828&token=0069911f2c4e6972f2d2c" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<h3>HEADING</h3>
```

For more information see: http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video